# Gift that adds Difficulty

Tags: world-of-darkness, content-identification, werewolf-the-apocalypse-2nd-edition

I heard there is a reflexive gift that allows one to pay variable gnosis to add a +2 difficulty per gnosis spent to attacks aimed at the targets mind. Does anyone know of a gift that is like this?

Answer (score 2):

A gift that raises the difficulty for attacks against the minds does instantly ring the bell of Shell (Metis Rank 3) from the W20 prints to me, but it is a full immunization, is a new one and so it clearly isn't this one. It does allow us to gauge that the gift we are looking for is most likely a rank 2 to 4 gift! So let's sift and see what we find...

**Mindblock**, a Silverfang/Stargazer Rank 4 gift, is very similar to Shell and I could trace it back to the revised edition core book, I can't find my 2nd edition core book at the moment.

> "Any direct mental attacks or
>   attempts to control the Garou's mind, as well as more insidious
>   psychic assaults (mind-reading, mentally implanting illusions
>   or possession) are raised to 10. The effects of this Gift are
>   permanent, but they do not apply to powers that sway emotion."

But I believe it is **Resist Temptation**, Stargazer Rank 2, *Tribebook Stargazers p.51* (which is 2nd Edition):

> The player rolls Wits + Rituals and spends one
>   Gnosis point. Each success raises others' difficulties to ensorcel
>   or supernaturally coerce the character by one. For instance, a
>   vampire trying to Dominate the Garou would find it harder to
>   succeed. Against non-supernatural coercion, this Gift is automatically
>   successful. Thus, mundane con artists and temptresses
>   have no power over the Stargazer.

Comment: While Shell does have its uses, I am not looking to handicap my character in this way. I have seen Mindblock and am considering it. However, Mindblock just sets the Diff to 10, which means specs can lower the Diff and most Mind attacks are at Diff Willpower. I REALLY like Resist Temptation and plan on picking it up. I am still hoping to find another Gift that is closer to what I am looking for,

Thank you for your response!